# Plus and minus function on dynamic button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I individually set `input` value when adding or removing item quantity, when the `button` and `input` are dynamic?

At the moment if I change quantity of an item, it updates all the inputs which I don't want to happened. Only want to update the quantity value of the item I clicked.

```
var drinks = data.categories.drinks;
        $.each(drinks, function (index, value) {
            $('#drink_list').append(
                '<div class="col-sm-4"> <div class="thumbnail">' +
                '<img src="./assets/imgs/' + value.image + '" alt="..."> <div class="caption">' +
                '<p>' + value.name + ' ' + value.liter + '<span class="pull-right">£' + value.price + '</span></p>' +
                '<p>' + '<button id="qButtonMinus" onclick="minus()">-</button> <input type="text" name="quantity" style="width:30px;" class="value"> <button onclick="add()" id="qButtonAdd">+</button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right" onClick="addToCart(\'' + value.name + '\',\'' + value.price + '\')"> Add </button>' + '</p>' +
                '</div> </div> </div>'
            );
        })

add = function () {
    currentQuantity++;
    $('.value').val(currentQuantity)
    console.log('Add > ', currentQuantity)
}

minus = function () {
    if (currentQuantity > 0) {
        currentQuantity--;
    }
    $('.value').val(currentQuantity);
    console.log('Minus > ', currentQuantity)
}
```

[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/4s7d8rxx/1/)

Answer (score 2):

I changed the code below:

```
add = function(obj) {
  var count = $(obj).siblings('input').val();

  $(obj).siblings('input').val(parseInt(++count))
  var at = $(obj).siblings('button.addToCard');
  var valcount = at.attr("onClick").split(',');
  at.attr("onClick", valcount[0] + "," + valcount[1] + "," + count + ")")
}

minus = function(obj) {
  var count = $(obj).siblings('input').val();

  if (count > 0) {
    $(obj).siblings('input').val(parseInt(count - 1))
    var at = $(obj).siblings('button.addToCard');
    var valcount = at.attr("onClick").split(',');
    at.attr("onClick", valcount[0] + "," + valcount[1] + "," + parseInt(count - 1) + ")")

  }
}
```

Now you have to pass an object into the functions: `onclick="minus(this)"` `this` takes the object you click on

**Update** You `btn` function now looks like `btn = function(item, price, itemCount)`

Run the code and it should work as you want

```js
var json = {
  "categories": {
    "drinks": [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Coke",
      "liter": "500ml",
      "price": 1.99,
      "image": ""
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Coke Diet",
      "liter": "500ml",
      "price": 1.99,
      "image": "/products/dietcoke-medium.png"
    }, {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Sprite",
      "liter": "500ml",
      "price": 1.99,
      "image": "/products/sprite-medium.png"
    }, {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Powerrade",
      "liter": "",
      "price": 3.59,
      "image": "/products/powerade-medium.png"
    }, {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Pure Life Water",
      "liter": "",
      "price": 1.49,
      "image": "/products/Pure-medium.png"
    }, {
      "id": "6",
      "name": "Refillable Mug",
      "liter": "",
      "price": 2.99,
      "image": "/products/Home-medium.png"
    }],
    "clothes": [{}]
  }
};
var cartItemArr = [];
var cartPriceArr = [];
var currentQuantity = 0;
var allItems = json.categories.drinks;
$.each(allItems, function(index, value) {
  $('#items').append(
    '<div class="col-sm-4"> <div class="thumbnail">' +
    '<img src="./assets/imgs/' + value.image + '" alt="..."> <div class="caption">' +
    '<p>' + value.name + ' ' + value.liter + '<span class="pull-right">£' + value.price + '</span></p>' +
    '<p>' + '<button id="qButtonMinus" onclick="minus(this)">-</button> <input type="text" name="quantity" style="width:30px;" class="value"> <button onclick="add(this)" id="qButtonAdd">+</button>' +
    '<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right addToCard" onClick="addToCart(\'' + value.name + '\',\'' + value.price + '\',0)"> Add </button>' + '</p>' +
    '</div> </div> </div>'
  );
})

add = function(obj) {
  var count = $(obj).siblings('input').val();

  $(obj).siblings('input').val(parseInt(++count))
  var at = $(obj).siblings('button.addToCard');
  var valcount = at.attr("onClick").split(',');
  at.attr("onClick", valcount[0] + "," + valcount[1] + "," + count + ")")
}

minus = function(obj) {
  var count = $(obj).siblings('input').val();

  if (count > 0) {
    $(obj).siblings('input').val(parseInt(count - 1))
    var at = $(obj).siblings('button.addToCard');
    var valcount = at.attr("onClick").split(',');
    at.attr("onClick", valcount[0] + "," + valcount[1] + "," + parseInt(count - 1) + ")")

  }
}


addToCart = function(item, price, itemCount) {
  console.log(itemCount);
  var itemQuantity = {};
  var item_quantity;
  var quantity;

  var increaseQuantity = 0;
  cartItemArr.push(item);
  cartPriceArr.push(price);

  // Sum up all items
  var totalPrice = 0;
  $.each(cartPriceArr, function() {
    totalPrice += parseFloat(this) || 0;
    $('.total').text(totalPrice.toFixed(2));
  });

  // Item quantity count
  for (var i = 0, j = cartItemArr.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (itemQuantity[cartItemArr[i]]) {
      itemQuantity[cartItemArr[i]]++;
    } else {
      itemQuantity[cartItemArr[i]] = 1;
    }
  }

  for (var drink in itemQuantity) {
    quantity = itemQuantity[drink] + "x ";
  }

  // Render items in virtual receipt
  $('.cart').append(
    '<div class="col-sm-6">' + quantity + item +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">' + price +
    '</div>'
  );
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="cart">
    <h3>Cart</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <div id="items">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool thanks, but how can I get each quantity value to add in `btn()` so I can `.append()` it like `(2) Coke` rather than doing `for()` in //quantity count line. If quantity is `0` then can't add basically.

Comment: Check it now and look if it whats you want, BTW if you question is not completly solved, dont mark a question as answer before you got it all working according to your question

Comment: Can you edit your snippet and change `addToCart()` to `btn()` and I get `.split()` of undefined

Comment: Done, rest of code should be simple for you to fix yourself. Since you marked the question as answer already not much point of keep trying to fix it all for you

Answer (score 0):

Make the on click in html to this `onclick="minus(this)"` and `onclick="add(this)"` Here's the [**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4s7d8rxx/6/)

```
add = function (elem) {
  var $main = $(elem).prev();
  var val = $main.val().length ? $main.val() : 0;
  val++;
  $main.val(val);
}

minus = function (elem) {
  var $main = $(elem).next();
  var val = $main.val();
  if(!val.length || val <= 0) return;
  val--;
  $main.val(val);
}
```

```js
var json = {
  "categories": {
    "drinks": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Coke",
        "liter": "500ml",
        "price": 1.99,
        "image": ""
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Coke Diet",
        "liter": "500ml",
        "price": 1.99,
        "image": "/products/dietcoke-medium.png"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Sprite",
        "liter": "500ml",
        "price": 1.99,
        "image": "/products/sprite-medium.png"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Powerrade",
        "liter": "",
        "price": 3.59,
        "image": "/products/powerade-medium.png"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Pure Life Water",
        "liter": "",
        "price": 1.49,
        "image": "/products/Pure-medium.png"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Refillable Mug",
        "liter": "",
        "price": 2.99,
        "image": "/products/Home-medium.png"
      }
    ],
    "clothes": [{}]
  }
};
var cartItemArr = [];
var cartPriceArr = [];
var currentQuantity = 0;
var allItems = json.categories.drinks;
$.each(allItems, function(index, value) {
  $('#items').append(
    '<div class="col-sm-4"> <div class="thumbnail">' +
    '<img src="./assets/imgs/' + value.image + '" alt="..."> <div class="caption">' +
    '<p>' + value.name + ' ' + value.liter + '<span class="pull-right">£' + value.price + '</span></p>' +
    '<p>' + '<button id="qButtonMinus" onclick="minus(this)">-</button> <input type="text" name="quantity" style="width:30px;" class="value"> <button onclick="add(this)" id="qButtonAdd">+</button>' +
    '<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right" onClick="addToCart(\'' + value.name + '\',\'' + value.price + '\')"> Add </button>' + '</p>' +
    '</div> </div> </div>'
  );
})

add = function(elem) {
  var $main = $(elem).prev();
  var val = $main.val().length ? $main.val() : 0;
  val++;
  $main.val(val);
}

minus = function(elem) {
  var $main = $(elem).next();
  var val = $main.val();
  if (!val.length || val <= 0) return;
  val--;
  $main.val(val);
}


btn = function(item, price) {
  var itemQuantity = {};
  var item_quantity;
  var quantity;

  var increaseQuantity = 0;
  cartItemArr.push(item);
  cartPriceArr.push(price);

  // Sum up all items
  var totalPrice = 0;
  $.each(cartPriceArr, function() {
    totalPrice += parseFloat(this) || 0;
    $('.total').text(totalPrice.toFixed(2));
  });

  // Item quantity count
  for (var i = 0, j = cartItemArr.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (itemQuantity[cartItemArr[i]]) {
      itemQuantity[cartItemArr[i]]++;
    } else {
      itemQuantity[cartItemArr[i]] = 1;
    }
  }

  for (var drink in itemQuantity) {
    quantity = itemQuantity[drink] + "x ";
  }

  // Render items in virtual receipt
  $('.cart').append(
    '<div class="col-sm-6">' +
    quantity + item +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">' +
    price +
    '</div>'
  );
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="cart">
    <h3>Cart</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <div id="items">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite, if you add 1 Coke then add a different drink it gives you value of 2 instead of 1.

Comment: @MrNew i know fixed!

Comment: Thanks, how can I get the quantity of each items then add it to `btn()` so it would show in the cart how many quantity of drink you have? like `2x Coke` as at the moment its `.append()` everytime you add a drink even if they're the same.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `button` html to

```
<button onclick="add(this)" id="qButtonAdd">
```

then change your `add()` method as

```
add = function (e) {
    currentQuantity++;
    $(e).prev('input').val(currentQuantity)
    console.log('Add > ', currentQuantity)
}
```

you can apply similar logic for `minus()`